# app engine localhost x online session

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, session, stripes

I am using stripes + google app engine.
On the localhost it works properly, but online there are problems:

- I am using `getContext().getMessages().add(new SimpleMessage(...))`. It works fine, but only once, after reloading the page and doing same things, it does nothing.
- I have a login page, that stores info about user in the session. I am using `.getContext().getUser()` or `setUser(User user)`. 

  getUser: `return (User) getRequest().getSession(false).getAttribute("user")`

  setUser: `if (user == null) {getRequest().getSession().removeAttribute("user");} else {getRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute("user", user);}`

  It's doing nothing(no user load in the session), but on the localhost it works fine.

I've tried Opera, Chrome, Firefox, IE, but always the same result.

It seems like there is a problem with getContext() method, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know too much about the Google App engine. But could it be that the Google App engine has the JSession still disabled (as per default). Stripes needs a JSession in order to work with the Stripes flash scope that is used for showing messages after a redirect.

Others write about fixing problems with Google App engine by providing an empty multi part wrapper:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/471992/java/java/Google-App-Engine-Simple-Stripes

Comment: I've already tried empty multipart wrapper, but don't work. And I have in my appengine-web.xml session enabled.

Comment: Did you check if you receice a JSession cookie each time?